# Logic error in C++ Visual studios. Array is printing address not the contents

Tags: c++, arrays

I am having a problem with my code in C++ Visual Studios. I have made an array MonthDays to store the days of the month inside of it. In a constructor function with DaysOfTheYear I have a string month setting the months to a integer placing that integer inside a checker variable. With that checker variable I am trying to print the contents of the Array but instead the array is printing to what I assume to be the address of the variable. Below is the code. On line 79 I have it to print the contents of the array inside the void print function but of course it is printing out the address.  I haven't made the code on line 79 to where If I entered 60 It would equal March 1st yet. I was just testing that part out to make sure I was printing out the right element in the array. On line 13 I declare MonthDays[12] in DayOfYear Class with 12 elements. On line 136 I have the MonthDays array defined with all the days of the month. Also I know that as is with the first constructor it works fine however I am supposed to add in a string variable and a integer variable to a new constructor that can determine the day in day-month format in that condition.

My output is as follows:

-8589934060 (This is what is supposed to be the contents of the array) Day 365 is December 31.
If anyone can help with this I will be grateful. Thank you all for reading this.

```
 // This program takes a user inputted integer and converts it to a month and day

 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <Windows.h>

 using namespace std;

 class DayOfYear
 {
     public:
         int MonthDays[12];
         int day;
         static string monthName;
         int checker;

         DayOfYear(int dayD)
         {
             day = dayD;
         }
         DayOfYear(int days, string month)
         {
             day = days;
             if (month == "January")
             {
                checker = 1;
             }
             else if (month == "February")
             {
                 checker = 2;
             }
             else if (month == "March")
             {
                checker = 3;
             }  
             else if (month == "April")
             {
                 checker = 4;
             }
             else if (month == "May")
             {
                 checker = 5;
             }
             else if (month == "June")
             {
                 checker = 6;
             }
             else if (month == "July") 
             {
                 checker = 7;
             }
             else if (month == "August")
             {
                 checker = 8;
             }
             else if (month== "September")
             {
                 checker = 9;
             }
             else if (month == "October")
             {
                 checker = 10;
             }
             else if (month == "November")
             {
                checker = 11;
             }
             else if (month == "December")
             {
                checker = 12;
             }

         }


     void print()
     {
         cout << MonthDays[checker - 1];

         if (day >= 1 && day <= 31)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be January " << day;
         }
         else if (day >= 32 && day <= 59)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be February " << day - 31;
         }
         else if (day >= 60 && day <= 90)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be March " << day - 59;
         }
         else if (day >= 91 && day <= 120)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be April " << day - 90;
         }
         else if (day >= 121 && day <= 151)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be May " << day - 120;
         }
         else if (day >= 152 && day <= 181)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be June " << day - 151;
         }
         else if (day >= 182 && day <= 212)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be July " << day - 181;
         }
         else if (day >= 213 && day <= 243)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be August " << day - 212;
         }
         else if (day >= 244 && day <= 273)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be September " << day - 243;
         }
         else if (day >= 274 && day <= 304)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be October " << day - 273;
         }
         else if (day >= 305 && day <= 334)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be November " << day - 304;
         }
         else if (day >= 335 && day <= 365)
         {
             cout << "Day " << day << " would be December " << day - 334;
         }
     }

 };


 int main()
 {
     int MonthDays[] = { 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 };

     DayOfYear tester(365,"February");
     tester.print();

     Sleep(5000);

 }
```

Comment: You're accessign MonthDays, the member variable, which is not initialized, instead of the one you declared in main which is actually never used.

Comment: Please reduce your code to a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You don't need to show (and explain) your entire program just to ask about a single output statement.

Comment: You have *two* and *different* arrays both named `MonthsDays`.

Comment: @StoryTeller IMO this is an MVCE, the description of the code is a bit overkill i'll give you that, but the code is fairly minimal and complete/verifiable. Its just long because of the verbose if/else chain.

Comment: Oh and you don't initialize `checker` if the first (one-argument) constructor is used. In C++ uninitialized variables will have a *indeterminate* value, and using them leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Borgleader - The verbose if/else chain is exactly what detracts from the minimal quality. And had the OP *tried* to create a MCVE, they'd have deemed it irrelevant too.

Comment: But that could be the faulty code! And its actually being used in reproducing the error you cant take it out.

Comment: @Borgleader - It could, or it could not (and we both know it isn't). The burden on the OP is to reduce the program to the problematic construct, not just dump it all here, and expect others to pour through it or debug it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes *we* know it isnt, were not the ones writing the question.

Comment: @Borgleader - Yes, the OP is. Which is why I pointed them towards the article that explains what a good MCVE *is*. I have no idea what you are taking umbrage with.

Comment: @StoryTeller Exactly, and each function (aside from the single argument ctor) is being used in the bug repro. They dont know the if/else chain is not the problem here. Its not an MVCE because you have a better understanding of the code than they do and *you* have been able to eliminate a greater part of it than they have as part of their debugging process. As far as I'm concerned this is an MVCE (if a bit verbose).

Comment: @Borgleader - It doesn't really matter how far you are I are concerned. There's a minimal burden of effort on every poster, detailed in the MCVE page, regarding how hard they should work to reduce a problem to a MCVE. As this code sample stands stands, it falls under the "bad" category [Eric Lippert](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) was talking about (and don't go excusing the OP based on the explanation, you yourself deemed it unnecessary). That's how the site operates, don't like it? Take it to meta. I'm done discussing it here, feel free to have the last word

Comment: Yep that was the problem BorgLeader. Thank you for your help and also thank you Some Programmer dude. I will keep that in mind for next time StoryTeller, thank you for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
 int MonthDays[12];
```

To:

```
constexpr static int MonthDays[12] = { 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365 } ;
```

This sets the class's array.

Also note that the line

```
cout << MonthDays[checker - 1];
```

accesses the class's `MonthDays` rather than the one you wrote in `main`

Comment: Thank you for the help Mikhail. I appreciate it. I changed it and yep it works as intended now.